# Why do I get no response from a URL Request in an Xcode Command-Line Application

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am having a problem in Xcode using swift. I tried to get data from a webpage using URL Requests in Swift. In the completion handler of the dataTask I tried printing the Data. This works fine in a cocoa app after enabling Arbitrary Loads in the info.plist file. But when I try to do the same thing in a Command-Line Application, it seems like the completion handler does nothing. The Terminal doesn't even show up after building. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a semaphore to block the current thread. Wait for the URL session to finish. From the completion handler, signal the semaphore.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your command line utility finished early. To avoid that, there are a few different possibilities. One most common uses dispatchMain() which never return and the command line utility should be stopped "programmatically"

put this in main.swift and try :-)

```
import Foundation

print("----------- init request -----------")
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let url = URL(string: "https://code-maven.com/try/examples/html/hello_world_html5.html") {
        do {
            let contents = try String(contentsOf: url)
            print(contents)
        } catch {
            fatalError("contents could not be loaded")
        }
        exit(0)
    } else {
        fatalError("the URL was bad!")
    }
}
print("---------- continue execution ------")
dispatchMain()
```